# Laravel - Não logar após cadastro.....?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, login, laravel-auth

Como remover o login automático após se cadastrar?

Eu comentei a seguinte linha do arquivo RegisterUsers:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }
        //Linha comentada
        //Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Isso impediu de logar mas tbm não cadastra o usuário.

Tentei deixar só o create:

```
Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->create($request->all());
```

Porém dá o erro: 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::create()'.

O que faço?

Comment: O método `create` faz parte do seu controlador, não da classe `Auth`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria mais fácil você pegar o model que é responsável pelo autenticação e usar o método `create`.

Mas posso adiantar que, no Laravel, o método responsável pelo login é o `Auth::login()`, que é chamado no final da sua linha comentada.

No seu caso, o código que precisa ser deixado para apenas criar o usuário é apenas o `$this->create()`.

Veja:

```
$this->create($request->all())
```

Comment: Vlw, funcionou!.